# I get an error when want to display specific data using "where"

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5

My table Users - >

```
Schema::create('mstanggota', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('no_anggota',10);
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

table Mstbeasiswas ->

```
 Schema::create('mstbeasiswas', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('no_anggota',10)->unique();
            $table->string('nm_anak',25);
            $table->string('kt_lahir',25);
            $table->date('ttl');
            $table->String('nm_skl',50);
            $table->String('st_pend',6);
            $table->String('lbg_pend',6);
            $table->String('prov_skl');
            $table->String('jenkel',9);
            $table->integer('k_umum');
            $table->integer('k_khusus');
            $table->integer('score')->nullable();
            $table->boolean('status')->default(0);
            $table->string('ket',250)->nullable();
            $table->string('img1',50)->nullable();
            $table->string('img2',50)->nullable();
            $table->string('img3',50)->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

I want to try to display data with controllers, the following code:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Mstbeasiswa;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder;

class BeasiswaController extends Controller
{


   public function index(){
    /*$datas = Mstbeasiswa::orderBy('id','DESC')->paginate(1);
    return view('home')->with('datas', $datas);

    */
    $user = Auth::user()->no_anggota;
    $user = Mstbeasiswa::table('mstbeasiswas')->where('no_anggota', $user)->first();
    echo $user->no_anggota;
   }


}
```

myerror ->

> BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2405:
>   Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::table()

help meee :(

Comment: the reason is `Mstbeasiswa::table('mstbeasiswas')` -- well if your `Mstbeasiswa` extends `Model`, you should not define the table name there.. but in the model.. could you post this `Mstbeasiswa`?

Comment: Remove the table()-call and try `Mstbeasiswa::where('no_anggota', $user)->first();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumed that you created an Eloquent model extending the Model class you can remove the `::table(...)` part and call

```
Mstbeasiswa::where('no_anggota', $user)->first();
```

But this will give you only one model. If you need a collection use `->get()` instead of `->first()` like so:

```
Mstbeasiswa::where('no_anggota', $user)->get();
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this was very helpful. < 3

Comment: No problem @SitiRahmah:) Please accept this answer.